# Goland not showing ec2 methods is there an indexer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, goland

I just installed `Goland` and it worked fantastic for working with the AWS `SQS` package code completion. However, I tried adding the `ec2` package from aws and its not showing me the methods attached. I cannot locate any code completion indexer which i thought would just reindex the code

Here's what my ec2 template looks like:

```
package awsbridge

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2"
)

type EC2Handle struct {
    client *ec2.EC2
}

var ec2Handle *EC2Handle

func NewEc2Handle() *EC2Handle {
    session := GetSession()
    ec2Service := ec2.New(session)
    ec2Handle = &EC2Handle{
        client: ec2Service,
    }
    return ec2Handle
}

func (e *EC2Handle) AcceptReservedInstancesExchangeQuote() {
    input:=&ec2.//no methods showing AcceptReservedInstancesExchangeQuoteInput
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-5793

The workaround for now is to open `Help | Edit custom system properties` and add there:

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=3000000
```